# Iterate over indexed dataframe and get the index of current iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
data = {'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit', 'Aishwarya', 'Priyanka'],
                'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18],
                'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Arts', 'Biology'],
                'Percentage': [88, 92, 95, 70]}
data = data.set_index('Name')
```

I want to iterate over the dataframe

```
for index, row in data: 
    # gives me the row I am at
    print(row)
    # how to print the index of the row
    print(index_of_dataframe)
```

How would I print the index of the dataframe of the current iteration I am at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = data.set_index('Name')

for i, (index, row) in enumerate(data.items()): 
    # gives me the row I am at
    print(row)
    #gives column name
    print(index)
    #gives position
    print (i)
```

Or maybe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = data.set_index('Name')

for i, (index, row) in enumerate(data.iterrows()): 
    # gives me the row I am at
    print(row)
    # how to print the index of the row
    print(index)
    print (i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for i in data.keys():
    #data[i] will give you values
    print(i)
```